Kill process based upon process Id powershell - xaml listview
I have a xaml listview with a button. The listview shows all processes that have powershell* or pwsh* in them. I want to be able to kill any of the processes by clicking a button but so far nothing I've tried has worked. Here is my code so far:
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
$input = @'
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PowershellListView"
        Title="End Processes" Height="450" Width="870">
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="btnEndProc" Content="End Process" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" Margin="112,341,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110"/>
        <ListView Name="listdisk" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Margin="12,107,-140,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="840">
           <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Process ID" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding ProcessID}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding Name}" Width="255"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Handle Count" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding HandleCount}" Width="105"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Working Set Size" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding Workingsetsize}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Virtual Size" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding VirtualSize}" Width="105"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
'@


#region code
[xml]$xaml = $input
$input = $input -replace '^window.*', '<window' -replace 'mc:ignorable="d"','' -replace "x:N",'N' -replace 'x:Class="\S+"',''

#Read XAML
$xmlreader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$xamlForm=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($xmlReader)
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object -Process {
    Set-variable -name ($_.Name) -Value $xamlForm.Findname($_.Name)
    }
#endregion code

$cim = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "Name like 'Powershell%' or Name like 'pwsh%'" 
$procids = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "Name like 'Powershell%' or Name like 'pwsh%'" | select-object -expandproperty ProcessId

#region XAML Controls

#endregion
$xamlForm.activate()
$listdisk.ItemsSource = $cim

$process = Get-Process -id $cim
write-host $process

$xamlForm.showdialog() | out-null

$btnEndProc.add_click({
    write-host "$listdisk.items.CurrentItem.ProcessId"
    $listdisk.items.currentitem.Processid.remove
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
    })

As you can see, at the end I was just doing some testing with the write-hosts but they're coming up empty. $procids is returning process ids.
Help please. I've been working on this for days.

I put 'powershell' in the title because when I was searching, I kept coming up with c# answers. I figured once it's answered it would help anyone else searching for a similar question.



Instead of $listdisk.items.currentitem.Processid.remove, use
Stop-Process -Force -Id $listdisk.items.currentitem.Processid in order to kill the process  corresponding to the currently selected list item showing the running PowerShell and PowerShell ISE processes.

Note: Stop-Process forcefully kills (terminates) the target process.

If you want to give the process a chance to shut down gracefully - which it may refuse, however - you can use
taskkill.exe /pid $listdisk.items.currentitem.Processid instead.


Also, Stop-Process terminates only the targeted process, not the entire process tree, i.e. not also any child processes (and their children) that may have been launched by it.

While powershell.exe and pwsh.exe themselves ensures that any child processes are also terminated, the PowerShell ISE does not do that.

To ensure that the entire process tree is terminated, make direct use of the underlying .NET APIs. Caveat: works in PowerShell (Core) 7 only:
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetProcessById($PID).Kill($true)






However, to ensure that $listdisk.items.currentitem truly reflects the currently selected list item, your XAML's <ListView> element is missing the
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" attribute.

A few asides:

Remove the "..." around the Write-Host argument (or use Write-Host "$($listdisk.items.CurrentItem.ProcessId)", though you do not need explicit stringification int his case; inside "...", expressions such as property access require enclosure in $(...).

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents(), which, despite relating to WinForms, also works in WPF for processing pending GUI events isn't necessary here, given that killing a process executes quickly and therefore doesn't interfere perceptibly with GUI event handling.

Your code mistakenly places $btnEndProc.add_click() after the .ShowDialog() call, where it wouldn't have any effect, given that .ShowDialog() shows the window modally (in a blocking fashion).





Below is a self-contained, streamlined, corrected form of your code that uses  Stop-Process to kill the selected process.
However, to be safe it uses the -WhatIf common parameter to preview the operation. Remove -WhatIf once you're sure the the correct process is being targeted.
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

[xml] $xaml = @'
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PowershellListView"
        Title="End Processes" Height="450" Width="870">
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="btnEndProc" Content="End Process" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" Margin="112,341,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110"/>
        <!-- 
          NOTE THE REQUIRED USE OF IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
          Also, to keep this demo simple, SelectionMode="Single" ensures that only ONE process can be selected at time.
        -->
        <ListView Name="listProcesses" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Margin="12,107,-140,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="840" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionMode="Single">
           <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Process ID" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding ProcessID}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding Name}" Width="255"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Handle Count" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding HandleCount}" Width="105"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Working Set Size" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding Workingsetsize}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Virtual Size" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding VirtualSize}" Width="105"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
'@ -replace '^window.*', '<window' -replace 'mc:ignorable="d"', '' -replace "x:N", 'N' -replace 'x:Class="\S+"', ''


# Parse the XAML and create PowerShell variables named for each control.
$xmlreader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$xamlForm = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($xmlReader)
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object -Process {
  Set-variable -name $_.Name -Value $xamlForm.Findname($_.Name)
}

# Get the processes of interest...
# NOTE: Using a [System.Collections.ArrayList] instance allows later modification of the list of processes, which
#       in turn allows removing items from the list view.
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $processes = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "Name like 'Powershell%' or Name like 'pwsh%'" 
# ... and bind them to the list control.
$listProcesses.ItemsSource = $processes

$btnEndProc.add_click({
    $selectedProcess = $listProcesses.items.CurrentItem
    $selectedProcessId = $selectedProcess.ProcessId
    Write-Verbose -Verbose "Forcefully terminating process with ID $selectedProcessId..."
    # NOTE: -WhatIf  *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.
    Stop-Process -Force -ID $selectedProcessId -WhatIf
    # Remove the terminated process from the list view and remove the selection.
    $listProcesses.items.SourceCollection.Remove($selectedProcess)
    $listProcesses.items.Refresh()
    $listProcesses.SelectedIndex = -1
  })

# Enable the button only if a list item is selected.
$listProcesses.add_SelectionChanged({
    $btnEndProc.IsEnabled = $this.SelectedIndex -ne -1
})

# Make sure that the window receives focus when it is first displayed.
$xamlForm.add_Loaded({ $this.Activate() })

# Show the WPF window modally (blocking call).
$null = $xamlForm.ShowDialog()


Thank you, this code is great and I see where my mistakes were. The only thing is, how do I remove the item from the listview after it has been terminated? It stops the process but still shows in the listview afterwards. I tried $listProcesses.items.CurrentItem.ProcessId.remove but that didn't do anything.

There is surprisingly little information on working with xaml and powershell unless you know c# and then it's still sketchy. Like, where did you find the bit about IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem I just found [This] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem?view=winrt-10586)

@MattWilliamson: Re removing the item from the list: please see my update; note the need to create $processes as a resizable [System.Collections.ArrayList] rather than a fixed-size array. After removing from the list, the selection is removed, which now disables the End Process button until another list item is deliberately selected; also, I've switched the XAML to single-selection mode, to keep this sample code simple. Working with WPF from PowerShell isn't easy, and there's no dedicated documentation I'm aware of; it's comparatively easier to work with WinForms instead.

Ok, I get it now. This is perfect! thanks. It would be nice if there was a comprehensive guide to xaml and powershell. I've just gathered together bits and pieces from all over the net. I use visual studio to create the xaml which makes it easier then remove the extra cruft.
